# .jar file no funciona a menos que se extraigan los archivos

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, .bat

soy nuevo en Java y he estado teniendo un problema con un "runnable .jar file". El .jar file de mi proyecto no abre pero cuando se extraen los archivos, sí. El proyecto usa imágenes mediante la clase Image de esta forma:
`Image img_bg = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("img/firtsLogin1.png")).getImage();`
`background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img_bg));`

**Ya intenté crear un .bat**. Esto es lo que muestra antes de extraer el .jar: [image: No funciona/abre el .jar]

Y así se muestra después de extraer el .jar:

[image: Sí funciona/abre el .jar]

Estoy haciendo algo mal con las imagenes? Mis imágenes estan colocadas dentro de un folder llamado img que esta dentro del Java project:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]